# Error 404 with tomcat9 container after deploying war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine
LABEL key="MyName"
ADD api.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

api.war is simple spring boot backend. Works on java 19. Deploy war file with `mvn clean package`
I've built the image `docker build -t api .` and ran the container `docker run -p 80:8080 --name test_api api`
Everything is successfull. Logs:

```
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 25 2017 21:08:02 UTC
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.2.0
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.345 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.349 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.457 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.479 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.487 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.491 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 699 ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.522 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.523 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
17-Aug-2023 21:55:54.555 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api.war]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.657 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.781 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api.war] has finished in [3,225] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.782 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [15] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [32] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.830 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [29] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [15] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:57.876 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:58.042 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [166] ms
17-Aug-2023 21:55:58.045 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:58.061 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Aug-2023 21:55:58.065 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3572 ms
```

In container in /webapps/ I have api.war
But when hit http://localhost:80/api I get a 404.

When I deploying that api.war file to my local tomcat 9 server, it works.
What's the problem?? Grateful for help

I've tried to specify tomcat image version. Change java version. Change war file name. And more other tutorials

Comment: The port should be 8080 I guess

Comment: Can try to hit this `http://localhost:8080/api`

Comment: When I run container `docker run -p 80:8080 --name test_api api` I specify port 80. And tomcat is working on this port. In port 8080 nothing(

Answer (score 0):

I change version of tomcat docker image to 9.0.79. And app works.